# Doctrine 2 DBAL expressions in update or insert methods

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dbal

I like the convenience methods for data manipulation queries $conn->insert() and $conn->update() in doctrine 2 DBAL because insert/update values can be held an passed as associative array. But how can i pass a NULL value, a MySQL function or other expressions as value?

E.g:

```
/* $conn is a \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection object */
$conn->update('person', array('phone' => 'NULL'), array('id' => 1));
$conn->update('person', array('lastlogin' => 'NOW()'), array('id' => 1));
$conn->update('person', array('visit' => 'visit + 1'), array('id' => 1));
```

These function calls would create prepared statements like

```
UPDATE person SET phone = ? WHERE id = ?
```

and thus the values would be treated as strings. 
Is there a way to make this work using this technique?

Answer (score 2):

There is an optional `$types` argument, which defaults to an empty array:

```
    public function update($tableExpression, array $data, array $identifier, array $types = array())
```

The `$types` array can contain [PDO type constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) which will change how the corresponding `$data` values are treated.

So I'd try:

```
$conn->update(
    'person',                          // $tableExpression
    array('phone' => null),            // $data
    array('id' => 1),                  // $identifier
    array('phone' => \PDO::PARAM_NULL) // $types
);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me using on ->insert... I sent NULL instead.